# How to pass vectors between multiple functions?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class PerformSort
{
    public:
    const vector<int> * p;
    vector<int>& getElements(int);
    vector<int>& sortArray(vector<int>&);
    void printer(vector<int>&);

}firstSort;

vector<int>& PerformSort::getElements (int num)
{
    vector<int> elements(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter elements into the array: ";
        cin >> elements[i];
    }

    p = &elements;
    return p;
}

vector<int>& PerformSort::sortArray (vector<int>& vector)
{
    int holder, min;

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(vector) - 1); i++)
    {
      min = i;
      for (int j = (i + 1); j < sizeof(vector); j++)
      {
        if (vector[j] < vector[min])
        {
          min = j;
        }
      }
      if (min != i)
      {
        holder = vector[i];
        vector[i] = vector[min];
        vector[min] = holder;
      }
    }


    return vector;
}

void PerformSort::printer(vector<int>& vector2)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(vector2); i++)
    {
        cout << vector2[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int numberOfTimes;
    cin >> numberOfTimes;
    firstSort.printer(firstSort.sortArray(firstSort.getElements(numberOfTimes)));
    return 0;
}
```

This returns the error: "invalid initialization of reference of type from expression of type". My first approach to create a SelectionSort algorithm was to try passing the vector by value (stupidly). After this I started to use pointers instead, after some research. However, this resulted in the aforementioned error. Declaring everything as constant does not seem to resolve the underlying error, despite how, if I understand things correctly, the error lies with temporary references being passed where constant ones are required. Any thoughts on how I might achieve this passing and returning of vectors? (I come from a Java background and am just beginning C++, so forgive me if I have made any obvious errors with regards to the pointers).

Comment: `p = &elements;` - Not a wise idea. Why not just use `p` in the first place and take out the pointer part of `p`? Also, you want `vector.size()`, not `sizeof(vector)`.

Comment: not too keen on the reference return from `getElements()` either, even if the pointer issue is addressed.

Comment: Why not use a regular vector (not a reference) in your class, change your 1st and 2nd methods so they return void, call the methods separately, and operate on the vector internally?

Comment: Hmmmm I like that idea, and may try to do that with the next piece of code I write. However, the quasi-functional style of doing things in just one line of code is something I find pretty cool.

Answer (score 4):

Return it by value:

```
vector<int> PerformSort::getElements (int num)
{
    vector<int> elements(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter elements into the array: ";
        cin >> elements[i];
    }
    return elements;
}
```

This will also let you get rid of `p`, which is a huge can of worms in its own right.

Finally, I notice that you use `sizeof(vector)` in quite a few places. This won't give you the number of elements in the vector; use `vector.size()` instead.

Comment: Returning by value causes run-time crashes for me. Regardless of whether the vector is called vector or otherwise (thanks Luchian).

Comment: @StephenRudd: `sizeof(vector)` is definitely worth fixing too.

Comment: Fixed sizeof(vector) and now I get another strange run-time error: list sorts fine, but then it starts outputting crazy large numbers. Thanks by the way chris. EDIT: Just me being stupid. Works fine. Thanks everyone, you've been very patient.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the variable `vector` to something else:

```
vector<int>& PerformSort::sortArray (vector<int>& wayBetterName)
```

&

```
return wayBetterName;
```

What urged you to name a variable the same as a type?

There's **many** more other issues with the code.

You don't need pointers, you don't need the references, plus you're better off just using `std::sort`.

Comment: Oh wow that was incredibly stupid of me. The code's not for functional use by the way, it was an old Java exercise I did that I tried converting to C++.